# Marklogic can't connect to EC2 after creating instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, marklogic

I have created an instance of marklogic via Market place and can't connect to 8001 port. Also tried to create ti via Cloud Formation and the same problem can't connect to 8001. I used the guides https://developer.marklogic.com/products/cloud/aws

I double checked several time Security groups and make sure 22 and 8001 are available publicly, but still no luck to connect. Could you advise me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Believe it or not, but it looks like the answer is in the little note in brackets (NB: MarkLogic AMIs will not run on micro instances). Therefore, I simply tried to create a small instance instead of micro and all worked.

Comment: i'm supprised marketplace even let you launch ML on an unsupported instance type